# Display users online using a pivot chart based on login and logout

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following table:

```
Id      Status     Date    
A      Log in   01.01.2018  01:44:03
A      Log out  01.01.2018  02:57:03
C      Log in   01.01.2018  01:55:03
C      Log out  01.01.2018  01:59:03
```

This table is inserted in a pivot table and I've tried to find out how many users are online within a certain timeframe. In our example, at 01:56 there are 2 user online (A and C). In the pivot table I did the following: In "Axis Field" I added the Id and Date and on the "Legend Field" the Status (Login and Logout). I added the data into a line chart and I have 2 lines, one for log in and one for log out. However, I can see the time where a user has logged in/out, but I can not see how many user are online. Any idea how I can fix this? Thanks!

For example these lines represents log in and log out

[image]

Comment: For an easy fix, rearrange your data. Arrnage the columns as `ID,Date,LogIn,LogOut` and then add one more column where you insert a formula to check whether `01:56` is between In and Out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes sorted data by `DateTime LogIn`.

[image]

Formulas:

- Column C: `=A:A&B:B` *Note this is string concatenation*
- Column F: `=D:D+E:E` *Note this is a real mathematical addition no string concatenation.*
- G2 and pull down: `=IF(C2=A2&"Log in",INDEX(F:F,ROW(C2)+MATCH(A2&"Log out",C3:$C$1048576,0)),"")`
- Column H: `=IF(AND(G:G<>"",$L$2>=F:F,$L$2<=G:G),"logged in","")`
- L3: `=COUNTIF(H:H,"logged in")`

Then just enter your test date/time in L2.

Comment: Note there was an error in determining the `DateTime LogOut` in my first version. This is fixed now by using another helper column `IDStatus`.

Comment: @PEH On the columns K and A you have "Test Time" and "Current Logged in". What kind of formulas have you used?

Comment: @CatalinVasilescu L3: `=COUNTIF(H:H,"logged in")`

Comment: @PEH It is possible to see in the same time how many users are online for more dates? Or for this is mandatory to create another column (like H) and count the "logged in". Thanks! I would like to insert this data into a scatterplot and I want to have different dates on the x axis and the number of online users on the y axis. Thanks!

Comment: @CatalinVasilescu It's possible to do it for multiple dates just make multiple columns like column H to count the logged in for each date, and eg put the date as header into the row 1. Give it a try.